# CodeBlocks 12.11, MinGW

Tags: c, openmp, codeblocks

I have CodeBlocks 12.11, mingw32-base (installed version 2013072200) (C language)

In compiler settings I have linked: ...\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\libgomp-1.dll.
And I added to other options "-fopenmp".

Program looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("Hello World!\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I try it all on Windows 7 x64, but i just can't seem to succeed in using this OpenMP, no idea what I'm doing wrong and google doesn't help.

The error, when trying to build is:

```
-------------- Clean: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Cleaned "Test - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g  -fopenmp    -c C:\Users\MStranko\Desktop\PROJEKT444\Test\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Test.exe obj\Debug\main.o    D:\Programy\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\libgomp-1.dll 
Execution of 'mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Test.exe obj\Debug\main.o    D:\Programy\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\libgomp-1.dll' in 'C:\Users\MStranko\Desktop\PROJEKT444\Test' failed.
Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).
```

I am new to using C and even newer to using OpenMP (sadly I'm still forced to). If I could receive any help, I'll be thankfull.

Comment: I just tried your code in my XP, and works fine.

Comment: I don't know, perhaps I need a tutorial on correct installing of codeblocks... no idea why it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to uninstall and reinstall it again? I remember that the first time also mine was not working properly.

Comment: You can also try another IDE, like Dev-C++.

Comment: Dino please post it as an answer so I can accept it, helped me a LOT! A simple Dev-C++ wiped all my problems away and I've been fighting this for over 10h with google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember that the first time I installed Code::Blocks was not working properly.  However, a simple but good IDE that I also use is Dev-C++.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use Dev-C++. If you look at its [download](http://www.bloodshed.net/index.html) page, you will see that it was last updated in 2005!

A simple solution presented [CodeBlocks Forum](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=13104.0) ::

> I met the same problem: in C::B, compiled a small OpenMP example but
>   got undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'. I have manually
>   compiled and linked the example using mingw-gcc, but it is OK.   g++
>   testOpenMP.cpp -o a.exe -fopenmp I then manually compiled and linked
>   standalone respectively,

```
    g++ testOpenMP.cpp -c -o testOpenMP.o -fopenmp

    g++ testOpenMP.o -o a.exe  (the same problem occurred.)
```

> If linked with -fopenmp, it is OK.
>
> Conclusion: C::B executed the linker to create execute, not with
>   -fopenmp link options.  The solution is  add gomp to the link libraries

Try it out :)

Comment: I tried this "In compiler settings I have linked: ...\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\libgomp-1.dll." since it didn't work I prefer Dev-C++. I dont really mind it being updated long ago, as long as it works. It's much more intuitive and what's more important, it works, contrary to C::B. Thanks for help anyways.